# What are the hypothesis of using linear discriminant analysis (LDA)?

Tags: topic-models

I want to use LDA for a classification problem.

- I have 14 independent variables including 11 continuous and 3 categorical variables.
- My response factors is binary {0, 1}.
- I have checked the normality of my continuous variables and it is OK.

My questions are

1. Could I use the categorical variables with LDA?
2. Should I report the co-variance?

   - If yes, what is acceptable for the covariances? Do they need to be close together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer might be *no*. One of the most cited arguments against LDA is that it is a parametric method (it assumes unimodal Gaussian likelihoods). If the distributions are significantly non-Gaussian, the LDA projections may not 
preserve complex structure in the data needed for classification. LDA will also fail if discriminatory information is not in the mean but in the variance of the data. Logestic regression tends to yield better estimate than does LDA if predictors include categorical variables.